# Monitoring JMX attributes with nagios check_jmx plugin

Tags: plugins, jmx, nagios, nrpe

I am monitoring JMX attributes with nagios plugin check_jmx. This plugin spawns mutiple processes named JMXQuery and the system hangs after that. What is the reason for that and how this plugin works?..please help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional information, it's hard to say what the issue might be, but it sounds like your plugin might not be able to connect to the intended end point. This problem is exarcebated by the absence of a [configurable] connect/read timeout in the standard JMX RMI remoting implementation, so in the event of a network issue (common issue with JMX-RMI) the launched JVM's will never connect and never terminate.

Perhaps you can launch JConsole on your nagios host and connect to one of the JVMs that is running the plugin and examine the thread stacks. Failing that, a **kill -3 PID** should send a thread dump to standard-out, hopefully revealing what the underlying problem is.